# Line by line searching using strstr

Tags: c, full-text-search

I've been trying to come up with a system that searches through a file line by line for a 6 digit number and when it finds it it breaks the loop and outputs the line it found but for some reason whenever I run my attempt the program just exits. Any help would be appreciated

```
        searching = 1;
        while (searching == 1) {
            search = 0;
            printf("Please enter the UP number of the student:\n");
            scanf(" %d", &w);
            while (search != 1) {
                fgets(line, 60, StudentDB);
                t = strstr(line, w);
                if (t != NULL && t != -1) {
                    search = 1;
                    printf("The student's data is:\n");
                    printf("%s\n", line);
                    printf("What would you like to do now\n1. Edit marks\n2. Delete record\n3. Search for a different record\n4. Return to menu\n");
                    scanf(" %d", &v);
                    switch (v)
                    case 1:

                    case 2:

                    case 3:
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ;
                        break;
                    }
               if (line == EOF) {
                    search = 1;
                    printf("There is no student with that UP number saved.\nWhat would you like to do?\n");
                    printf("1. Search for a different number\n2. Return to the menu\n");
                    scanf(" %d", &v);
                    switch (v) {
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            searching = 0;
                            search = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                } else {
                    printf("Something went horribly horribly wrong");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Run through this piece of code line by line through a debugger (and you will find out why)

Comment: What type of variable is `w`? If it's an `int`, then you can't use it in `strstr`; it it's a `char[]` string, then you can't read it with the `%d` format.

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, **complete, and verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have a look at the link, to check for it.  It is not possible to verify appropiately your code as you posted just a snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot search for a number with `t = strstr(line, w);`

The second argument to `strstr` must be a string. You should define `w` as a `char w[7];`, read the 6 digit number as a string with `scanf("%6s", w)` and use `strstr(line, w)` to find the number in the line.

Note also that `t != -1` makes no sense, `t` should be a `char *`, which will be either `NULL` if the number is not present or a valid pointer into the line if `strstr` found the number on it.

Similarly, it makes no sense to test for end of file after searching the line: at the end of file, `fgets()` returns `NULL` and the line was not read.